# Stream of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, stream, marshalling

I'm generating a series of JSON objects on the fly and want to stream them to some JS in the browser. However calling JSON.Parse or $.getJSON and similar functions won't work, as the data isn't a single object, but several consecutive objects.

Expected:

```
["first", "second", "third"]
```

Actual:

```
"first""second""third"
```

How can I parse each object separately from the stream? Other languages also complain with errors of "unexpected data". Is there a precedent for this? Should I be doing it another way instead?

Answer (score 2):

Use Event Source / server sent events as format, that'll chunk it up for you...